# : was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a bat file that does some basic functions for server builds. The script is made to be somewhat interactive. This allows us to use on script for Production, Dev, or QA. The area of the script that fails is below

```
echo Enter User-defined Information about this Server:  
echo Environment:  
echo    1. PROD     
echo    2. QA  
echo    3. Dev  
echo  Choose one:   
CHOICE /C 123  
if errorlevel 1 (set ENVIRONMENTNAME=PROD & set ENVNAME=Production)  
if errorlevel 2 (set ENVIRONMENTNAME=QA & set ENVNAME=Acceptance)  
if errorlevel 3 (set ENVIRONMENTNAME=Dev & set ENVNAME=Development)
```

Once I am prompted to "Choose One:" I choose either of the options then get the error:
: was unexpected at this time.

Comment: doesn't fail for me. I guess this is only a subset of the script, as I would expect a 'echo off' on the first line of the script.

Comment: That script by itself works for me. What comes after the errorlevel stuff?

Comment: The rest of the script is as follows:

Comment: Nvm. I noticed where the problem is but it seems to work at times then other times it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `@echo off` or `echo off` commands from the top of the script (or add `echo on`), and use the resulting output to debug which line causes the offending error.

For optimization purposes, put your `if errorlevel` commands in descending order.  The `if errorlevel` command triggers when the `ERRORLEVEL` is the specified number **or higher**.

Comment: Reversing the `if errorlevel` order will break this script unless you add `else`s as well

Comment: I see the line that errors out but its weird that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: if you reverse the if statements order in the OP script without changing anything else, all statements will still execute, but this time the output will always be 1, because 3 and 2 are >= 1, and 1 will be the last number checked against.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a rather belated answer, but I've just experienced exactly the same error message, although it was a "set /p" that was causing the problem for me. The line was originally:

```
set /p Option=Do you want to go ahead and load the data? ([Y]/N):
```

and the solution I found was to put double quotes around the prompt text, so:

```
set /p Option="Do you want to go ahead and load the data? ([Y]/N): "
```

Don't know if that will help anyone or not, but it solved the problem for me :-)

Comment: I have seen this behaviour as well. Specially regarding variables in the environment path: cmd doesn't like path with spaces in them although there are plenty of examples of such for various applications (eg C:\Program Files\...). Enclosing the path within double quotes is usually a good practice.